# Add method of ArrayList which return the list after adding not boolean

Tags: java, optimization, lambda

There is a method in java that add item in list and returns the Array List.

Indeed, the current ADD method returns boolean :

```
myList.add("other");  // return boolean
```

---

There is something like ?

```
myList.addAndReturn("other"); // return the List itself after adding
```

or :

```
Arrays.add(myList,"other")
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Still not understood whats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, there is however a `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` which creates a copy on all mutative operations (add, set, and so on)